# angular how to go back to a page with pagination?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

for example:
there is a page A, and page A has pagination, I page down to page 3,
then I goto page B,
finally, I am in page B now, I want to goback to **page A whit page 3**
how can I do it whit angular.js?

Comment: You need to save in a service what page you were on in page A. So if you're on page 3, then save it in the service. When you go to page B (do the same for this, save what page) and then want to go back to page A, the routing logic picks up the page (page 3 in this case) from the service. This is if I've understood what you're asking correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Do it as you would normally adding `<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">[Go Back]</a>` on the template.
And definning the routes to hold parameters: `/A/:page/`.

Example:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/A/:page',
  {
    controller: 'ACtrl',
    resolve: {
      result: ['$route', 'AService',  function ($route) {
        return AService.getPage($route.current.params.page);
       }]
     }
  });
}]);

app.controller('ACtrl', ['$scope', 'result', function (result) {
  $scope.results = results
}]);
```

Then you can retrieve the data for this page using the parameter in the url.